# How do I determine what is using the folder?

Tags: rm

I just can't delete the folder under root (it says that resource/device is busy), but lsof and fuser tell me nothing. The folder is located in the depth of /var/www/... and I tried to delete it after I stop apache2 and nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`sudo lsof +D /var/www/dir_name`

Once you know which processes have files open, you can exit those apps, or kill them with the `kill` command.

If you had a partition mounted to that point, you should  `umount` first.